# Cassandra vs Hbase for real-time data

Tags: cassandra, hbase, high-availability, bigtable

I'm looking a distributed, real-time data access tool. I've read that HBase is the HadoopSQL solution which is a Java clone of Google Big Table, but is more suited for batch jobs than real time access (and is slow because of all the read-write). I've also read that Cassandra is for "high availability".

Is my understanding of this correct? Is Cassandra better suited for a real-time database (that's distributed) than HBase or BigTable?

Comment: Note that Bigtable and HBase have similar data models, and Cassandra is partially derived from Bigtable, but Bigtable has [higher performance than either HBase or Cassandra](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/05/introducing-Google-Cloud-Bigtable.html) for both low-latency real-time operations as well as bulk read/write workloads. All of these databases are distributed and support high availability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Cassandra better suited for a real-time database (that's distributed) than HBase or BigTable?

Yes, Cassandra is more suited to an OLTP workload whereas HBase is more suitable for an OLAP workload, **in general**

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Bigtable...  From [the cloud bigtable docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/)

> Cloud Bigtable is Google's NoSQL Big Data database service. It's the
>   same database that powers many core Google services, including Search,
>   Analytics, Maps, and Gmail.
>
> Bigtable is designed to handle massive workloads at consistent low
>   latency and high throughput, so it's a great choice for both
>   operational and analytical applications, including IoT, user
>   analytics, and financial data analysis.